# Merge: [charging] into [battery]

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

I don't see why [charging](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/charging) should be a seperate topic area from [battery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/battery), any battery will need to deal with charging, and any 'battery expert' is also going to know how to troubleshoot charging issues of batteries.

The tags should be merged and synonymised.

Thoughts?